# How to create a loop and new data set from the function I created?

Tags: python, pandas, function, loops, dataframe

I have this real estate data:

```
neighborhood  type_property  type_negotiation  price
Smallville       house           rent        2000
Oakville       apartment       for sale      100000
King Bay         house         for sale      250000
...
```

And I created a function that sorts through this large data set by the neighborhood you input and if it's a house for sale, and then returns the 10th and 90th percentile and quantity of these houses. I have it here below:

```
def foo(string):
    a = df[(df.type_negotiation == 'forsale')&(df.type_property == 'house')&(df.neighborhood == string)]
    b = pd.DataFrame([[a.price.quantile(0.1), a.price.quantile(0.9), len(a.index)]],
                     columns=('tenthpercentile', 'ninetiethpercentile', 'Quantity'))
    return b

print(foo('KingBay'))



  tenthpercentile  ninetiethpercentile  Quantity
0         250000.0             250000.0         1
```

I want to write a loop that does this for the list of neighborhoods that I have, and then compiles each return in a new dat a frame. Looking something like this:

```
          tenthpercentile  ninetiethpercentile  Quantity
King Bay         250000.0             250000.0         1
Smallville        99000.0             120000.0         8
Oakville          45000.0             160000.0         6
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often with dataframes, it's better to avoid an explicit loop if you can, and use the optimized methods provided by `pandas`. In your case, you can do away with the loop by using `groupby` with [`describe`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.describe.html), passing your desired percentiles to the argument `percentiles`. Then, just select the desired columns and rename them appropriately:

```
new_df = (df.groupby('neighborhood')
          .describe(percentiles=[0.1,0.9])
          ['price'][['10%','90%','count']]
          .rename(columns={'count':'Quantity',
                           '10%':'tenthpercentile',
                           '90%':'ninetiethpercentile'}))
```

In your case (because there is only one example from each neighborhood):

```
>>> new_df
              tenthpercentile  ninetiethpercentile  Quantity
neighborhood                                                
King Bay             250000.0             250000.0       1.0
Oakville             100000.0             100000.0       1.0
Smallville             2000.0               2000.0       1.0
```

**[EDIT]**: I just saw in your function you were only looking at `(df.type_negotiation == 'for sale') & (df.type_property == 'house')`. For this, just add a `loc` to filter you dataframe by those conditions:

```
new_df = (df.loc[(df.type_negotiation == 'for sale')
                 & (df.type_property == 'house')]
          .groupby('neighborhood')
              .describe(percentiles=[0.1,0.9])
              ['price'][['10%','90%','count']]
              .rename(columns={'count':'Quantity',
                               '10%':'tenthpercentile',
                               '90%':'ninetiethpercentile'}))
```

Also, if you were attached to using your function and a loop (not that I would recommend it), you could do:

```
pd.concat([foo(i) for i in df.neighborhood.unique()])
```